# how to drop foreign key relation in the mysql table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have one table X. I need to drop all the foreign keys in the table. I don't know how to drop. Can any one please say the query.

Answer (score 6):

probably, you should  get the foreign keys using

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE <your_table>
```

then delete the foriegn keys one by one

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP FOREIGN KEY <key_name>;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to structure view of the table
2. You will see 2 options at the top 
    
   a. Table structure  
   b. **Relation view**.
3. Now click on **Relation view** , here you can drop your foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Read this will help you http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14347
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp
The foreign key constraint has to be dropped by constraint name and not the index name. The **syntax is:**

```
alter table test_table drop foreign key test_tableconstraint
```

Comment: Okay.But if i list the foreign keys after the deletion means it'll display again deleted foreign key.